# Is it okay to use "because" at the end of a sentence in casual talks?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, conversation

I'm reading a book written by a non-native speaker, in a paragraph it says something like this:

> A: Does the thought of two people of the same sex being attracted to each other make you uncomfortable?
> B: This would be absurd for real, I’m drawn to people of different genders, because.

The line by "B" uses the word "because" at the end of that sentence.

I personally know the author so I asked her. She told me it's okay to use because at the end of a sentence in a conversational style. We are both non-native English speakers, but she's very confident this happens in her daily life when she is living in the US, even for native speakers.

Is she right about this?

Comment: Firstly -- did the author explain what she thinks "because" means in this context? Secondly -- can you post the actual text, rather than "something like" it? There's a lot of room for nuances to be missed if you're paraphrasing dialogue you don't understand.

Comment: All I can say as a native speaker is that I have no clue what B means. It does not even sound like youth slang; there are instances in informal, usually rather vague, speech where “because” ends a sentence. It is similar to using “you know” and “like” randomly: it usually signifies a recognition on the part of the speaker that the utterance is confused, confusing, or both; it is a plea for mercy on the part of the speaker for having failed to have, let alone express, a cogent thought. Such handwaving happens frequently; that does make it a model to be followed.

Comment: It is very casual & generally indicates that the "continuation" is **(A)** something every body knows ( I was dressed up like a witch because [ it was holloween ] ) or **(B)** something obvious ( I want to eat because [ I am hungry ] ) or **(C)** something speaker does not want to tell ( I want a knife because [ I can not tell that I want to murder ] ) or **(D)** something too long to explain ( I want to go to the mall because [ reasons ] ) or **(E)** something speaker does not know ( I was told to open the gate because [ I do not know ] ) : Use it informally !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an idiom - '*just because*' - that has a usage slightly beyond the word 'because'. It would seem that some just say 'because' to mean the same thing. Of course, you can use the words 'just because' to lead into a stated reason for something, but the implication of the idiom alone of giving 'just because' as a reason alone suggests that either (i) there is no good reason and was perhaps just something done on a random whim, (ii) the reason should be plainly obvious, or perhaps (iii) the person does not want to explain their reasons and it is perhaps none of the enquirer's business.

I'm not completely sure your friend has used it correctly, but perhaps they had previously explained something about their sexuality that did not require repeating and by saying 'because' they were tacitly referring back to it, ie *because of the aforementioned*.